# Can I generate the dataset that formed a specific cluster?

Tags: time-series, subset, cluster-analysis

I am working with a very large time series dataset. I have clustered the dataset into 12 clusters. Cluster 0 comprises 39,301 instances of the 56-attribute dataset. I have the summary report using WEKA which shows the mean and std of each of the 56 attributes for the cluster. So, how can I generate or visualize this dataset/cluster of 56 x 39,301 matrix, using WEKA or Python.
Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I want to treat this clustered data as a subset of the entire dataset.